# How to get the user status in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to get [this user status](https://photos.app.goo.gl/2FRNAeBbbKqpTi2y5) from the Office 365 Admin Center like, blocked, unlicensed or E1 for example, in Microsoft Graph?

I tried several requests but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AccountEnabled attribute to find out if the user is blocked or not.

Make the attribute available using the [select](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#select-parameter) query parameter:
"/users/?$select=AccountEnabled"

Add whatever other attributes you need:
"/users/?select=id, businessPhones, displayName, givenName, jobTitle, mail, AccountEnabled"

You can also use the [filter](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter-parameter) parameter to filter blocked users:
"/users/?$filter=AccountEnabled eq true"

Answer (score 0):

Browsing the Microsoft Graph doc, I found information about this endpoint: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_licensedetails

It doesn't seem to exactly match the data you're looking for, but it does provide in-depth details about software licenses a user is attached to, from which this status seems to be computed.

Best regards!